# How to remove anchor tag from URL in React

Tags: reactjs

So I have a single page application built in React, and I want to have it so when I click a link in my navbar it scrolls to that component but doesn't change the URL or adds the href anchor to the URL.

For example, when I click the "About" link it scrolls my page to where I have the About component but changes the URL from "localhost:3000" to "localhost:3000/#about". What can I do so when I click any link in my nav bar it scrolls to where I have that component displayed but leaves the URL as "localhost:3000"?

Here's my navbar code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './styles.css';

class Navbar extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="navbar">
                <li> <a href="#about"> About </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#experience"> Experience </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#education"> Education </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#portfolio"> Portfolio </a> </li>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use scrolling and disable the link logic:

`<a onClick={this.onClickAbout.bind(this)}> About </a>`

and add the method:

```
private onClickAbout(e) {
e && e.preventDefault(); // to avoid the link from redirecting
const elementToView = document.getElementById("idOfAbout");
elementToView.scrollIntoView(); 
}
```

And make sure `About` has that id when defined
`id="idOfAbout"`

Comment: Thank you so much! After modifying it a little I got it working. I'll post the updated code below as an answer so everyone can see it.

Comment: Nice! Glad to see it helped, sorry if it didn't work at first, it's coded from :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Updated and working code:**

```
import React from 'react';
import './styles.css';

class Navbar extends React.Component{

    onClickAbout(e) {
        e && e.preventDefault(); // to avoid the link from redirecting
        var elementToView = document.getElementById("about").scrollIntoView();
        }

    onClickExperience(e) {
        e && e.preventDefault(); // to avoid the link from redirecting
        var elementToView = document.getElementById("experience").scrollIntoView();
        }

    onClickEducation(e) {
        e && e.preventDefault(); // to avoid the link from redirecting
        var elementToView = document.getElementById("education").scrollIntoView();
        }

    onClickPortfolio(e) {
        e && e.preventDefault(); // to avoid the link from redirecting
        var elementToView = document.getElementById("portfolio").scrollIntoView();
        }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="navbar">
                <li> <a onClick={this.onClickAbout.bind(this)}> About </a> </li>
                <li> <a onClick={this.onClickExperience.bind(this)}> Experience </a> </li>
                <li> <a onClick={this.onClickEducation.bind(this)}> Education </a> </li>
                <li> <a onClick={this.onClickPortfolio.bind(this)}> Portfolio </a> </li>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 1):

DRY approach. (base code taken from other 2 solutions (OP and Francesc Montserrat )). This should not be the accepted answer.

```
import React from 'react';
import './styles.css';

class Navbar extends React.Component{
    constructor() {
       super();
       this.navigate = this.navigate.bind(this); 
    }
    navigate(e, id) {
       e && e.preventDefault(); // to avoid the link from redirecting
       const elementToView = document.getElementById(id);
       elementToView .scrollIntoView(); 
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="navbar">
                <li> <a href="#" onClick={(e=>this.navigate(e, 'about'))}> About </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#" onClick={(e=>this.navigate(e, 'experience'))}> Experience </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#" onClick={(e=>this.navigate(e, 'education'))}> Education </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#" onClick={(e=>this.navigate(e, 'portfolio'))}> Portfolio </a> </li>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Navbar;
```